# v0.4.22 solc compile failing - not predictable behavior

Tags: solc, compilation, error, constructor

Error:

```
 Warning: Defining constructors as functions with the same name as the contract is deprecated. Use "constructor(...) { ... }" instead.
  function CappedCrowdsale(uint256 _cap) public {
  ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
 not valid for functions.oc tag @dev
Compilation failed. See above.
```

I got this same exact error when my token contract was not using the new `constructor()` convention.

What is odd, is after I switch the **token** contract to the new convention, the compiler was happy. The next day it did the same thing, broke and complained about my **crowdsale** contract not using the new convention. (weird it didn't complain about this the day before) This was last week. I resolved the issue by switching to `constructor()`.

Now I did a `git pull` on my laptop to continue work today, and now it's not happy with the constructor call made to the inherited contract, `CappedCrowdsale`.

```
function CappedCrowdsale(uint256 _cap) public { ^ (Relevant source part 
starts here and spans across multiple lines).
    not valid for functions.oc tag @dev
```

Googling has not turned up anything helpful. And troubleshooting on my own has not turned up any positive outcomes. I'm not 100% sure the `constructor` convention causing this error as it's only deprecated. But perhaps something related around that?

`not valid for functions.oc tag @dev
Compilation failed. See above.` - leaves me clueless

Edit: I've restarted my computer and now compile doesn't give any warning about the `constructor` convention. Only the 1 liner error above. Last week this occurred on my desktop. Today is on my laptop.

Edit x2: Narrow down the issue to the laptop. Same code base is working without issue on my desktop. Perhaps something needs updated/reinstalled? Will update when I figure it out. The warnings are separate, nonrelated, to the compile failure.

Comment: The constructor message is just a warning, the code should continue to work. The message about CappedCrowdsale is incomplete, add a few lines before it where more information should appear. Difference between desktop and laptop might be different solc versions.

Comment: The code does not work as I get `Compilation failed. See above` (I forgot to include that line on the very bottom - just now fixed). Solc versions are the same as it gets pulled from the package.json file in the tooling setup and there are no global instances installed via NPM.

Comment: Are you on windows? Did you try to compile on linux? I remember having an issue with @dev tags on windows. For some reason tags cannot be by themselves at the end of a line, ie `// @dev` will fail but `// @dev Dummy` will work. This also happened with other tags like `@title` etc. This issue appears to be unrelated to the warnings.

Comment: Correct I'm on windows. I've had the same issue as you with no characters trailing `@dev` before as well. 

I do agree that the warnings and compile issues are unrelated as well.

I've narrowed this down to the laptop; as the same project works without issue on my desktop. i will to try narrow down exactly what is breaking on my laptop and update here if I find the solution.

Comment: Same project - still the same result. 
Tried removing and adding solc & truffle via yarn.
Tried deleting the repo and cloning again.
Did a NPM list -g -depth=0 to see global instances - none related solidity.

Works on my desktop without issue though. Very odd.

Comment: Okay did a global search for '@title' and '@dev' tags. 

I had a '@dev' tag with nothing trailing it ... smh... lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@dev` & `@title` tags need trailing characters. As stated by Ismael

Breaks:
`@dev`

Works:
`@dev constructor`

The odd thing I haven't figured out, yet, is the difference between both my machines. Both being Windows 10. My laptop is the that throws the error. My desktop does not.